# Error in model selection (gamm4) dredge function (MuMIn R package): family not recognised, model skipped

Tags: r, github, mumin

I am trying to do model selection for generalized additive mixed models (made using [gamm4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamm4/gamm4.pdf) using the [MuMIn](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf) package in R.
I am essentially trying to follow [this](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/inst/doc/gamm.pdf?revision=91&root=mumin&pathrev=91) piece of literature for model selection with MuMIn and gamm4.

I am creating a model with 9 variables, and a random individual effect - which looks likes this:

```
library(gamm4)
library(MuMIn)
SouthFull = gamm4(OtoWidth ~ s(Ages) + 
                 LagFinFSLdat_AnnEsts +
                 FSL_months_Feb +
                 LagFSLdat_Annual +
                 LagFSLdat_Spring +
                 LagFSL_months_Oct+
                 FinFSLdat_SummerDat +
                 FinFSLdat_AutumnDat +
                 LagFSL_months_Nov , random = ~(1|FishName), data = South)
```

But when I try to use the `dredge` function, it fails with the error message:

```
(dd <- dredge(global.model=SouthFull))
Error in dredge(global.model = SouthFull) : result is empty

    In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
    > warnings()
    Warning messages:
    1: In gamm4::gamm4(...) : family not recognized (model 1 skipped)
    ...
    50: In gamm4::gamm4(...) : family not recognized (model 50 skipped)
```

Is this due to a problem with MuMIn not recognizing the gamm4 model family?

Full code & data can be found at my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/emboylen/EBHonoursThesis/tree/master/8.%20Modelling/StackOverflowHelp) and the specific issue is in the code [gamm_analysis.R](https://github.com/emboylen/EBHonoursThesis/blob/master/8.%20Modelling/StackOverflowHelp/gamm_analysis.R), with the specific warnings found at line 81.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the post.

Comment: Is that a little better? Anything I missed?

Comment: Seems that your code has been written to work with some **very** old version of MuMIn. Try without including "Extgamm4.R" and read `?uGamm`.

Comment: Ok, now I noticed that you're referring to MuMIn's vignette from 2011 (which has long been removed but obviously is still available through R-Forge's svn). So you definitely should use and follow the manual for the current version.

Comment: OK thank you @Kamil Barton - I have tried running my scrip without "Extgamm4.R". Now when I run `dredge(SouthFull)` I get the error message:
`Error in nobs.default(global.model) : no 'nobs' method is available` - any advice?

Comment: have you read `?uGamm`?

Comment: Yes I did, but I obviously didn't read it closely enough @KamilBartoń. I have updated my script after reading `?uGamm`, so now it looks like this:
    `Stest = uGamm(SouthFull)`
    `getCall(Stest)`
    `update(Stest)`
    `dredge(Stest)`

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am havig the same issue with gamm4. `Error in nobs.default(global.model) : no 'nobs' method is available`

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, did anyone ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is something wrong with the package. I have the same error. Then, I tried to run the example available in the help of the function dredge of the MumIn package to see what I am doing differently and I get the same error even using the example below:

```
fm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement)
dd <- dredge(fm1)
```

The error message is:

```
Error in nobs.default(global.model) : no 'nobs' method is available
```

Comment: This does not happen normally. Perhaps try the example in a clean workspace.

Comment: I always get this result. I was trying in Rstudio before and now I tried in R without using Rstudio, just copying and pasting the example and still get the same error... I don't know what is happening...

Comment: Interesting. Are you using a current version of R and MuMIn? You can also check if `nobs(fm1)` works (R should not look for `nobs.default` but rather for `nobs.lm`).